# Unable to use DHT11 with NodeMCU(esp8266)

Tags: nodemcu, temperature-sensor

I am trying to use a NodeMCU like an arduino,trying to read Temperature and Humidity using a DHT11,but when ever I check the serial monitor the it outputs : nan, Can anyone help me find the problem.(The data pin is D4 on NodeMCU)

```
    #include "DHT.h"

DHT dht2(2,DHT11);

    void setup()
    {
      Serial.begin(9600);

    }


void loop()
{

    Serial.println("Temperature: ");
    Serial.println((dht2.readTemperature( )));
    Serial.println("Humidity");
    Serial.println((dht2.readHumidity( )));
    delay(5000);

}
```

[image]

Comment: use D1 or D2. D4 has a pullup resistor https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402066/esp8266-free-gpios-for-relay-switching/404845#404845

Comment: Thanks manhh, you rock!!

Answer (score 1):

The esp8266 boot configuration pins 0, 2, 15 require a pull-up/pull-down  to ensure the required state at boot. The board (NodeMCU in this case) has pull-up resistor on io0 and io2 and a pull-down resistor on pin 15. The MCU pins io0, io2 and io16 are the NodeMCU pin D3, D4 and D8. You can use this pins in the sketch, but only to attach devices which are not in conflict with the required boot state and are not disturbed by the pull-up/pull-down.

**NodeMCU and "Wemos D1 R2 and Mini" esp8266 pins and io overview**

---

**Serial**

RX io1 RX0

TX io3 TX0

---

**boot config pins** with pullup or pulldown on board

D3 io0 PULLUP (LOW for boot to flashing mode)

D4 io2 TX1 PULLUP (Serial1 TX. no RX for Serial1)

D8 io15 PULLDOWN (SS pin if esp8266 is SPI slave)

---

**untroubled GPIOs** with optional function for I2C or SPI bus:

D1 io5 default pin for I2C SCL

D2 io4 default pin for I2C SCA

D5 io14 SPI CLK

D6 io12 SPI MISO

D7 io13 SPI MOSI

---

**RTC pin** for timed deep sleep wake-up (if connected to reset pin)

D0 io16 - optional internal pulldown, internal pullup not available

---

**not useable**: S*x* pins io 6 to io 11 connect QIO SPI flash memory (in DIO flash mode the 2 QIO pins can be used as gpio) (in a very special setup the SPI bus can be used with other SPI device)

*note: most digital IO start as INPUT_PULLUP*